# Comma separated list of values as different rows, not as fields for one row, for an SQL INSERT

Tags: sql, mysql, insert

I want to make many inserts in a single SQL statement, pretty much like
`INSERT INTO xxx SELECT field FROM zzz`

But with values I don't have in a table, and are just a list of literals.
Normal way would be executing one SQL query for each value, but if there exists a standard SQL statement, or MySQL-specific, it would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`insert into xxx (fields) values (values1), (values2), (values3)`

eg `insert into mytable (name, desc) values ('name1','desc1'), ('name2','desc2'), ('name3','desc3'), ('name4','desc4')`

Comment: MySQL, PostgreSQL, and MS-SQL-2008 support this kind of multi-row insert.  Sorry, I can't remember if Oracle allows it.

MS-SQL-2005 and earlier do not, so you have to use remi bourgarel's approach instead (select union select union etc....) which works on everything.

In general (with either approach) I would probably avoid doing more than 2000 inserts at a time, especially with the 'select union select union select....' approach.  I found it really got slow in groups of 4000 rows on MS-SQL-2000, and so I've been hesitant ever since.

Comment: Most of the database engines also have non-sql ways to load data directly from files (e.g. CSV).  These tend to be much faster, sometimes even 100 times faster if you drop indexes first, but personally I prefer portable SQL, and this is fast enough.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into xxx(afield)
select 'a'
union
select 'b'
union
select 'x'
```

will give you a table like that :

### afield

a

b

x